# KeyInput won't work in python (pygame.K_LEFT)

Tags: python, pygame

I have a program where you have a object and need it to move around asteoids. But in the while loop when i press the arrow keys nothing outputs or works for that key.

```
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop=False

        if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

            if (event.type==pygame.K_LEFT):
                direc1 = -5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event type won't ever be the keyname, you have to check event.key after testing for a keypress.

```
if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):
    if (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
            direc1 = -5
```

Comment: It says event is not defined

Comment: you still need your pre-existing code, just replace that second nested if with what I wrote (ie change event.type to event.key)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I did find out that you cant have  pygame. or it didnt work for me.